# Is Internet Explorer 10 limited to Windows 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8

I couldn't find it on the internet anywhere. I know that it has a Metro version and a regular version, so since Microsoft isn't supporting Metro with earlier versions of Windows, I'd understand if it would be hard to release it for earlier OSs, but it still seems unlikely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present yes, however a new preview of IE10 for Windows 7 is expected mid-November.

There is no public guarantee that a final version will come to Windows 7 - only official line is that it will depend on "developer and customer feedback". [(Source)](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/10/internet-explorer-10-preview-to-hit-windows-7-in-mid-november/)

Update: [It appears IE10 will come to W7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie10-on-windows-7-available-in-november)

Comment: Alright, thanks, it would be stupid of them to walk away from all of that market share.

Comment: an IE upgrade isn't really important for older windows versions. And a lot of people (me) have already moved to Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Well at school we've been using XP until this year, and we'll probably be using Windows 7 until I graduate, so it's important for me and everyone in the class. haha

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 10 is not available on Windows 7 right now. It seems however that there are plans to release it for Windows 7. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The IE10 preview is now released to Windows 7:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie10-fast-fluid-perfect-for-touch-and-available-now-for-windows-7)