# Internet Explorer 10

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Internet Explorer 10 limited to Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/493619/is-internet-explorer-10-limited-to-windows-8)

Can **Internet Explorer 10** be used with other versions of **Windows**?(Windows 7,XP etc).What are the User Interface versions avaialble for Windows 8 with **Internet Explorer 10**?Will there be any Platform specific changes(64 bit and 32 bit) while using it with Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well only for Windows 7. But for versions lower than that it will not be possible. IE10 will come out for Windows 7 in a couple of weeks. (November 2012)

Source - [PCMag](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2411096,00.asp)

Comment: The version that will be released in November will be a `Preview` release, although said release, will be fully functional.  The clarification is important since the final release date has not been annouced.